Почему при прописывании в роут Route::get('/files/disk' возвращает 404, а Route::get('/file/disk' возвращает нужный ответ?
В Postman при прописывании в роутах files ошибка 404, хотя в роутах прописано
Route::get('/files/disk', [FileController::class, 'listUserFiles']);  

а при замене на
Route::get('/file/disk', [FileController::class, 'listUserFiles']); 

нет ошибки. В чем принципиальная разница для files и file?
Route::post('/registration', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/authorization', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
Route::get('/user/show', [FileController::class, 'show']);

Route::post('/files', [FileController::class, 'upload']);
Route::patch('/files/{fileId}', [FileController::class, 'rename']);
Route::delete('/files/{fileId}', [FileController::class, 'delete']);
Route::get('/files/{fileId}', [FileController::class, 'download']);
Route::post('/files/{fileId}/accesses', [FileController::class, 'addAccess']);
Route::delete('/files/{fileId}/accesses', [FileController::class, 'removeAccess']);
Route::get('/file/disk', [FileController::class, 'listUserFiles']);
Route::get('/shared', [FileController::class, 'listSharedFiles']);
});


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

А где у вас в коде get('/files/disk' ? Вижу только get('/file/disk.

@Kromster , приведенный выше код рабочий.  А если прописывать get('files/disk... не работает

Так вы допишите это в вопрос, может у вас там опечатка или ещё что :-)

Вам надо ваш роут располагать выше вот этого: Route::get('/files/{fileId}', [FileController::class, 'download']);

конечно банальный ответ, но может вам нужно почистить кэш роутов? php artisan route:clear
